# libgit2 GIT_BUF_INIT undeclared; where should it be declared?

Tags: libgit2

I'm running through the `libgit2` [sample code for getting the content of blobs](https://libgit2.github.com/docs/guides/101-samples/#objects_lookups), and I've hit a problem with the line:

```
git_buf filtered_content = GIT_BUF_INIT;
```

I get error `C2065: 'GIT_BUF_INIT': undeclared identifier`, which makes sense, because I can't find this defined in any of the included header files. As nobody seems to have asked this question before I get the strong feeling I'm missing something obvious. Any ideas on what I need to do to use `GIT_BUF_INIT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's declared inside the library because it references an internal buffer. You should zero the structure as usual for C.

If the examples contain `GIT_BUF_INIT` they were probably extracted from the tests and we missed that it's not available outside.

Comment: I'm new to C, and I'm not sure how to create the structure without knowing the size it should be. I tried: 
 char initbuf[0];
 git_buf filtered_content = { initbuf, 0, 0 };
but I can't allocate a zero-sized array. How do I initialise filtered_content so that it can be filled in?

Comment: You do know the size, it's `sizeof(git_buf)`. You can zero it out via `memset` or by doing something like `git_buf buf = { NULL }`